# Disable dimmend undefined sourceceode vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VSCode, the editor dimms the color of the source-code which has been uncommented by defines.

Eg:

```
#ifdef SOMETHING_NOT_DEFINED
// This sourcecode has dimmed color.
#endif
```

How can you disable this?
Is there a setting, and if not, what is the color-setting for this?

Comment: No idea what this language is, but you can try setting `"editor.showUnused": false,` (which is suppose to control the dimming of unused code)

Answer (score 9):

I found the answer myself.
Just put

```
"C_Cpp.inactiveRegionOpacity": 1
```

in your settings.json file.

Comment: Thank you!  You can also get to this from the settings->extensions->c/c++->C_Cpp: Dim Inactive Regions.